# Can I set two string value for CodingKey?

Tags: swift, encoding

Something like:

```
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id" = "some_id"
    case name
    case tags
    case text
  }
```

I need this because stucts of my entity on backend have same fields besides `id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nope, but you can do some kinda 'hack' under the hood like that:

```
struct BusinessObject: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case primaryId = "id"
        case alternativeId = "some_id"
    }

    private let primaryId: Int?
    private let alternativeId: Int?

    var id: Int {

        return primaryId ?? alternativeId ?? 0
    }
}
```